# Individual user table or main table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm writing a portal that allows users to comment on specific threads. Each thread has multiple "subscribers" that are alerted that a comment has been added by an update script that runs once a minute.

If I'm running a MySQL database, would it be more efficient to have a thread table for each user, and have each added comment update multiple tables, and have the update script just access each user's table, or have a main thread table with the `file` column indexed, a permissions table linking which users have access to which files, and use SQL syntax "AND `file` IN ('1','2'...)" when the update script runs?

my hosting company gives me unlimited storage, so space isnt an issue

thanks

Comment: Never do that and make data specific tables like a table for each user. Never!

Answer (score 1):

Keep it in one table. In most usage scenarios this will be faster (if properly indexed) use less resources, and it will keep your code much simpler.

Using multiple tables breaks a fundamental design rule for relational databases.

Comment: Also using a single table will make your queries much easier. You won't need to work out which table to select from, or perform UNION queries - you can just select from a single table.